# Why can the server send an incorrect response or how can I avoid the 500 error?

Tags: python, flask, whatsapp

I'm trying to make a chat bot for whatsapp, I ran into this problem

```
   "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1953, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1968, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2098, in make_response
    "The view function did not return a valid response. The"
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
```

I use Flask, this is what my app.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from WhatsApp.wabot import WABot
import json

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
        bot = WABot(request.json)
        return bot.processing()


if (__name__) == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I also have a WhatsApp directory with wabot.py, since I'm calling processing (), here's its code

```
import jmespath
import requests
import datetime
import logging
import time
import json
import sqlite3

class WABot():
def __init__(self, json):
    self.json = json
    self.dict_messages = json['messages']
    self.APIUrl = '...'
    self.token = '...'

def send_requests(self, method, data):
    url = f"{self.APIUrl}{method}?token={self.token}"
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
    answer = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
    return answer.json()

def send_message(self, chatID, text):
    print(text)
    data = {"chatID": chatID,
            "body": text}
    answer = self.send_requests('sendMessage', data)
    return answer


def write_to_db(self, id, str):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('dataWhatsApp.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?;''', (id,))
    result = cur.fetchmany()
    if len(result) == 0:
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO users VALUES(?, ?);''', (id, str))
    else:
        cur.execute('''UPDATE users SET path=? WHERE id=?''', (str, id))
    conn.commit()


def get_path(self, id):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('dataWhatsApp.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?;''', (id,))
    result = cur.fetchmany()
    return result[0][1]

def doSomethingWithMsgText(self, info, text, id):
    if (text == "/start"):
        path = "start[*].cmd"
        self.write_to_db(self,id, path)
        self.send_message(self, id,
                     "...")
        self.send_message(self,id,
                     "...")
    else:
        path = self.get_path(self,id)
        array = jmespath.search(path, info)
        if array is None:
            self.send_message(id, "Неизвестная команда")
            return
        if (len(array) > 0):
            for i in range(len(array)):
                if (array[i] == text):
                    path = path.replace("*", str(i))
                    try:
                        self.send_message(id, jmespath.search(path[:len(path) - 4] + ".message", info))
                        path = path[:len(path) - 4] + ".child[*].cmd"
                        self.write_to_db(id, path)
                    except BaseException:
                        self.write_to_db(id, path)
                        self.send_message(id)
                        return
        else:
            print("end")

def getanswer(self, id, text):
    with open('info1.json', encoding="cp1251") as f:
        d = json.load(f)
    if (text == "Назад"):
        path = self.get_path(id)
        if (path != "start[0].child[*].cmd"):
            backpath = path.replace("].child[*].cmd", "")
            backpath = backpath[:len(backpath) - 1] + "*].cmd"
            path = backpath
            self.write_to_db(id, path)
            backmessage = backpath.replace("child[*].cmd", "message")

            self.send_message(self,id, jmespath.search(backmessage, d))
        else:
            self.send_message(self, id, "Невозможно вернуться назад")
    else:
        self.doSomethingWithMsgText(self,d, text, id)



def processing(self):
    path = "start[*].cmd"
    if self.dict_messages != []:
        for message in self.dict_messages:
            text = message['body'].split()
            if not message['fromMe']:
                id = message['chatId']
                return self.getanswer(self,id,text[0])
```

The fact is that I am trying to transfer my bot from telegram to WhatsApp and the bot logic is correct, all the files used are located next to app.py, I will be glad of any help.

Comment: just from a quick glance, your processing calls getanswer but get answer does not return anything

Comment: @HarshaLimaye ,but getanswer() call self.send_message() which subsequently returns json

Comment: I think it will return to the calling function again. Which itself has no return statement. Try putting one and see if anything changes